# SUPEE-6788 Yields htaccess issue

Tags: patches, supee-6788

The first time I ran the patch, I got

> patching file .htaccess Hunk #1 FAILED at 207. It was the only file that had an issue.  All the rest patched successfully.

I replaced with the stock .htaccess and .htaccess.sample, and ran the patch again.  This time, new .htaccess issue:

> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>   /usr/bin/patch: **** Can't rename file /tmp/polM4FGJ to .htaccess : Permission denied
>   ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

I've checked all permissions, everything seems to be okay. Anyone run into this?

Comment: What is the output of 'ls -l .htaccess .' and 'id'

Comment: what operating system, and are you running the patch as the uid that owns the files in the magento installation?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the file permissions, issue seems to be that the file is not writable.
Change the file permissions and make it writable.

Answer (score 0):

please refer below link is useful for your problem

https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/1-9-1-0-applying-patch-6788-hunk-failed/td-p/20070

Comment: Thank you.  I've tried all those methods, with no change in result.  I'll keep monitoring that forum.